# How to align multiple artboards in Adobe Illustrator CS4

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

I have a bunch of artboards in a file and I want to align them accurately, like the way I can align graphic objects with Align panel. The alternative is to use a grid and align them manually with a mouse but may be there is a better way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CS5 has this easy option - not sure about CS4 :

Object > Artboards > Rearrange

you can then dictate direction and spacing of the multiple artboards - hope this helps

Comment: Can confirm for CS6.

Comment: Can confirm for Illustrator 2022

Answer (score 1):

First make the shapes as same as the artboards you need and align them. Then, go to File/Document Setup/Edit Artboards and click on each of the shapes you want to transform. CS4 automatically will create a new artboard according to the object you draw. Finally, click on the selection tool to return to your artwork. Now you just have to erase the objetcs you create first and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right in CS4, once artboards, you can't align them with the Align palette. But I know that in CS5 you can make the shapes to your liking first, align them, and then convert them to artboards using Object > Artboards > Convert to Artboards. Perhaps CS4 also has this option?